# How to tell Pip where to cache wheel files?

Tags: python, pip

When I install packages onto my Linux server using Pip, I'd like for pip to cache the wheels it downloads into a directory other than the default, which is ~/.cache/pip.  I'm trying to specify the cache directory as 'pkg_cache' in my ~/.config/pip/pip.conf file like this:

```
[global]
index-url = http://packages.example.com:8081/simple
extra-index-url = https://pypi.org/simple
trusted-host = packages.example.com
download-cache = $HOME/project/pkg_cache
```

But when I do my 'pip install' the wheel files aren't being saved in the pkg_cache directory, even if I set the permissions to that directory to 777.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `$HOME`. Pip's configuration file is not a shell script and there is no shell variable expansion. Try using a concrete path instead.

Also check the configuration options of your `pip` with `pip --help`. I have version 10.0.1 and there is no such option as `download-cache`, but there is `cache-dir`:

> `--cache-dir <dir>           Store the cache data in <dir>.`

Answer (score 0):

Pip also listens to the global variable `PIP_CACHE_DIR`.
So to set pip's cache directory, use

```
export PIP_CACHE_DIR=$HOME/project/pkg_cache
```